# Создать таблицу из JSON файла

Tags: python, json

Появилась необходимость выводить таблицу, сформированную с помощью python из JSON данных, но выводить не в текстовом формате, а в картинке. Не могу найти нормальную библиотеку для этой задачи. Желательно чтобы название столбцов можно было менять на понятный язык.

Еще вопрос: Можно ли сохранять эту таблицу в памяти, а не записывать в файл? Если же нельзя, то какой результат получится, если одновременно передать 2 разных JSON файла?

P.S. Боюсь придется вручную писать цикл для формирования таблицы и ее уже переводить в jpeg формат. Может кто знает нужные библиотеки или сервисы для этого?

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Comment: Можно попробовать или вручную рисовать картинку с помощью Pillow (норм, если структура таблицы простая и нет длинных строк), или генерировать HTML/Excel, потом конвертировать в PDF, а из него или сразу в JPEG 